# Is there a way for the App to change notifications into silent notifications (not server) for push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, push-notification

I was wondering if it is possible for an App to turn a push notification that isn't silent(plays sound) into a silent push notification (doesn't play sound)? From my research it seems that only the server can change non silent notifications into silent push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunatly impossible.

The advantage of the push notification is that it can be presented to the user event if the app is not running.

The drawback is that your application is not told about push notification receiption. Thus, you cannot modify it in the app.

Another solution would be to use background fetch to ask your server for notifications, and then to programm UILocalNotification with/without sound.

But doing this, your notifications would't work while the app is not running